How do I move a task to a different To-Do list?
In Spirit City: Lofi Sessions, I setup two To-Do lists for Work tasks and Personal tasks. I then created some personal tasks in the Work list by mistake and want to move them to the Personal list. Dragging and dropping the task to the other list had no effect.
How do I move tasks to a different To-Do list?

